# Generate a random combination from a vector's data

Tags: c++, random, combinations, combinatorics, shuffle

Note, I mean the [mathematical combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), where order of the sequence does not matter:

> In mathematics a combination is a way of selecting several things out of a larger group, where (unlike permutations) order does not matter.

I am trying to randomly pick n elements from a vector of size M. n is typically M / 2 (integer division, flooring in case M is odd).

The algorithms I have been using are [std::shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/), then taking the first M / 2 elements.

The random generator and uniform distribution functions took around 70 % of my execution time, so I have also tested my own version that stops shuffling after half the vector:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class URNG>
inline void half_shuffle (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                          URNG&& g)
{
    const unsigned half = (last - first) / 2;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < half; ++i) {
        uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> d(i, last - first - 1);
        swap (first[i], first[d(g)]);
    }
}
```

First, I wonder if this looks correct. In the test rig I could come up with, the results look uniform, *even* on the second half of the resulting shuffled vector (I am calling the half_shuffle function on the same vector many times in a row, so this could be the reason).

Second, these functions are supposed to give a random *permutation* of n out of M elements. This means that the order of the n chosen elements is itself random. This extra randomness is of no interest to me, and I wondered if this information could help reduce the computation time even further, by sacrificing the randomness in order.

Comment: You could simply perform M/2 coin tosses and skip an element half the time.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but I am not sure I understand. The code above already performs M/2 random number generation. Even the reservoir sampling needs M/2 random number, doesn't it?